# Traefik - How to log the request_body

Tags: traefik

I am new to Traefik and trying to find a way to capture and log the request_body. In Nginx by adding $request_body in nginx.conf it will log the body in access.log. Is this possible in Traefik ?

Thanks

Comment: The [feature](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/6704) was requested but denied.